Access linux python venv for Pycharm CE indexing
Is it possible to use linux-created venv at a shared location for indexing within windows Pycharm CE?
I have a linux venv, with several linux-exclusive libraries installed. So I cannot just replicate the venv in windows.
But the development is done within PyCharm Community Edition on Windows, and I want the intelliscence to recognize these linux-exclusive libraries.
This can be achieved within PyCharm Pro, but is it possible to do within Pycharm CE?
Even something hacky like copying the venv/lib/ to the windows venv would be fine for me if it worked.
Tried pointing Pycharm to the venv, it wouldn't allow me to select the linux interpreter binaries.

There is a way
Copy the Linux venv directory to your Windows machine.
Then
Open PyCharm CE on Windows and then go to File > Settings > Project Interpreter.
Click on gear icon next to the interpreter dropdown and select "Add"
Choose "Existing environment" and navigate to the copied venv directory.
if PyCharm did not detect the interpreter correctly. Then, manually select the Python interpreter binary within the venv's "bin" directory.
Click ok
This should work.
EDIT: There is a document about venvs and about configuring it https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-virtual-environment.html
